# finding 10 largest integers in an array in O(n) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Let S be a set of n integers stored in an array (not necessarily sorted). Design an algorithm to find the 10 largest integers in S (by creating a separate array of length 10 storing those integers). Your algorithm must finish in O(n) time.

I thought I could maybe answer this by using count sort and then adding last 10 elements into the new array. But apparently this is wrong. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: Add the first 10 numbers in the new array. Then just scan the remaining elements and keep updating the new array.

Comment: to easy, thank you!

Comment: wait im not sure this work?

Comment: Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect?

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**
you can use FindMax() algorithm that find the max number in `O(N)` and if you use it 10 time :

```
10 * O(N) =O(N)
```

each time you find max num you put it in the new array and you will ignore it the next time you  use `FindMax();`

**Method 2:**

you can use Bubble 10 times:

```
1) Modify Bubble Sort to run the outer loop at most 10 times.
2) Save the last 10 elements of the array obtained in step 1 to the new array.

10 * O(N) =O(N)
```

**Method 3:**

You can use `MAX Heap`:

```
1) Build a Max Heap in O(n)
2) Use Extract Max 10 times to get 10 maximum elements from the Max Heap 10
* O(logn)

 O(N) + 10 * O(logN) = O(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [order statistic](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~dekai/271/notes/L05/L05.pdf) algorithm to find the 10th biggest element. 
Next, iterate over the array to find all elements which are lesser/equal it.

TimeComplexity: O(n) for order statistic + O(n) for iterating the array once =>  O(n)

Comment: the worst case in that case is almost O(N^2)

Comment: @OneManCrew  It is O(n) in worst case.  http://www.cse.ust.hk/~dekai/271/notes/L05/L05.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Visit :

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/

They have mentioned six methods for this.

Answer (score -1):

Insert them in a balanced binary tree. O(N) + O(lg2 N).